# Postgres backup from on premise to the cloud

Tags: postgresql, offlineapps, odoo

I will like to deploy an application (powered by Postgres) offline, but i want it to synchronize with a backup online where the data can be safe and revert to any time. I will like pro's here to give me a headstart on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, you are looking for some form of log-shipping replication. Start reading here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html

If that goes over your head, start with [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) and transferring the files.